# What are Azure's First Class Citizens?

Tags: azure, operating-system, cross-platform

What languages/os are currently a first-class citizen on Azure?

Just from a short Google search, I'm seeing:

- .Net
- Node.js
- Java
- Docker
- Linux
- Windows (assuming)
- Open-Source
- [PHP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlining/2012/06/19/the-new-windows-azure-sdk-for-php/)?

is anything else a first-class citizen? Or where can I find out that information.

Comment: How do you define "first-class citizen"? You can run anything you want on an Azure VM.

Comment: That's a question in and of itself. Wikipedia says: "an entity which supports all the operations generally available to other entities." I'm pretty sure as of April 14th, 2017 Python is not a first-class citizen on Azure? https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/335